# Implementing DTLS handshake for the Bluetooth low energy devices

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, dtls, mbedtls, l2cap

I am  trying to implement a DTLS handshake between two BLE devices. For this, I wanted to use the L2CAP channel of the BLE to communicate with the messages coming from the DTLS. Basically, I want to open a DTLS tunnel with the help of L2CAP from the BLE stack. I am using the mbedTLS library for this. From the documentation of MbedTLS (https://tls.mbed.org/kb/how-to/how-do-i-port-mbed-tls-to-a-new-environment-OS), I understood that I need to set the mbed_tls_ssl_set_bio() function which has the read and write call back functions that communicates with the BLE top layers(L2CAP). I am using the dialog's DA14695 dongles for the implementation. I am not very sure about the read and write call back functions that needs to be written to communicate with the L2CAP channel of the BLE. Somebody experienced with opening a TLS/DTLS tunnel with the BLE top layers can help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Any reason you don't want to use TLS instead of DTLS? The L2CAP channels are "reliable" channels. TLS is made for reliable communication channels while DTLS is made for unreliable channels such as UDP.